# .net/exchange: add email addresses dynamically?

Tags: .net, asp.net, email, exchange-server

I'm building a .NET application where I want to dynamically add an email address for users when they create an account, so that they can email themselves things to their account and see it in the app.

The email address would be something like [account_name]@[site.com].

Is there a good reference URL to read which explains how to do this?
I'm in a ASP.NET/Exchange environment, but I'm willing to read articles dealing with other mail servers.

Apparently this is a difficult question to answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft Knowledge Base article explains how to create a new Exchange user and mailbox using DirectoryServices:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313114

Hope that helps!